# What should I replace getGlobalContext() with in LLVM 3.9.1?

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-clang

Doing old tutorials, I often see getGlobalContext() used. However, in LLVM 3.9.1, this function can no longer be found.

What should I replace these calls with for equivalent behaviour?

Answer (score 9):

you just can use

> static LLVMContext TheContext;

Answer (score 2):

I found this review very useful: https://reviews.llvm.org/rL266379

It shows the tutorials being changed in llvm/docs to match the new API.  They are replacing `getGlobalContext()` with code to allocate an `LLVMContext` to match the usage (static if it's being used with a static `IRBuilder`, for example).

So basically, make your own `LLVMContext` instead of using `getGlobalContext()`.